# Absolute positioning inside relative positioning?

Tags: css

According to W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp):

> Relatively positioned elements are often used as container blocks for
>   absolutely positioned elements.

Why is this? Is there a good example?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A good example would be when you want to position something to the page or "relative" to a container/div.

Here is my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/RdWQ7/2/

This shows you that without the absolute div being inside of a "relative" div, the contents are aligned to the document body.

Notice that the green div (`#box1`), which has `position: relative`, the div inside (`#inner1`) it is aligned top/right INSIDE of `#box1`.

The blue box (`#box2`), which has the exact same HTML layout as the green box (`#box1`), does NOT include `position: relative` and notice that the div inside it (`#inner2`) is aligned to the top/right of the `body`

```
#box1, #box2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
}
#box1 {
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
#box2 {
    background: blue;
}

#inner1, #inner2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

---

Here is a good article about it from Chris Coyier...

> A page element with relative positioning gives you the control to
>   absolutely position children elements inside of it.

Source: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't completely answer the question.  The inner divs are positioned relative to the first parent div that does not have the default positioning of static. So, if we make box2 have positioning of absolute we get the same result as relative.  This begs the question what is so special as having parent div as relative?  Thanks

Comment: @MoreThanFive You could do that, but now your `#box2` div is going to move inside of the body as if it were now `#inner2`. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/RdWQ7/3/ I added `right` so you can see how they are different.

Answer (score 20):

What the other answers don't explicitly state is this:

Absolute positioning is measured out in the nearest ancestor that doesn't have static positioning. Giving an ancestor relative positioning is just a means to this end. It doesn't have to be relative, it just can't be static.

An element with absolute position and

top:10px;

will be 10 pixels from the top of the closest ancestor whose position isn't static.

Comment: Dope, thank you, this is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

If an absolute positioned element isn't in a relative element then when you set top, left, right, or bot with a value, it will move the absolute position element from the body by that value. 
What does this mean? For example if you set an absolute position element's attribute, top, to 10px, it will push the element 10 pixels from the top of the screen.

If an absolute position element is in a relative element then when you set top, left, right, or bot with a value, it will move the absolute position element from that relative element by that value.
What does this mean? For example if you set an absolute position element's attribute, top, to 10px, it will push the element 10 pixels from the top of relative element. There you can move the relative element around and the absolute positioned element inside of it will always be 10 pixels from the top of the relative element.