# What is the difference in behavior of this two pairs of tags(see in)?

Tags: html, css, web

First example

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div style="position: relative; top: 10px">text</div>
</div>
```

Second example

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px">text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position Relative vs Position Absolute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-position-absolute)

Comment: @ctwheels: not exactly; the question is also asking about the complexity of absolute positioning inside of relative positioning see http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Fair enough. If that's the case, would it not be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283417/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first will position the inner div 10px top relative to where it would be positioned.
The second will position the inner div 10px top to where it would be positioned ignoring the padding and border of the outer div, and removing it from the flow of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Well an absolutely positioned element does not take up space in the dom so the outside div would have no height. That's one thing it does. I would encourage you to read up on it and just test things out in a codepen though, this isn't really the place for this.

Answer (score 0):

The first will leave a "ghost" behind of the moved element. The second takes it fully out of the flow of the document.