# How to get the ace editor to adjust to its parent div

Tags: html, css, ace-editor

I have the ace div inside another div and I would like the ace editor to adjust it's width and height to the parent div. I call editor.resize() but nothing happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor { 
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
<div style="background-color: red; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<div id="editor">function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}</div>
</div>

<script src="ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

    editor.resize();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve what you want in two manners. I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1x9pgn2u/1/) showing the css and javascript used to resize the ace-editor to its container.

The css used is to make it so the editor takes up the width and height of the container, so that `editor.resize()` can properly calculate the size the editor should be.

I recommend the following to get the `editor.resize()` to work.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

However if you want to maintain using the current css you have for `#editor` the following will work.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor {
        position: absolute; /* Added */
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
   }
</style>
```

and add `position: relative;` to the container, so that the absolutely positioned editor is correctly positioned inside its container. As to how this works I refer you to [Absolute positioning inside relative positioning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283417/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning)

Comment: Your logic adjusts the height but not the width. right?

Comment: Both the height and width should be adjusted. That is what the 100% on both height and width is for.

Answer (score 9):

I got it working with simple CSS:

```
#container{
    height:80vh;
}

#editor {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

The key property is `position:relative`, overriding the default `position:absolute` of the ace editor, which produces the parent container being unable to adjust its content.

```
<div id="container">
    <pre id="editor">
        &#x3C;div&#x3E;
        &#x9;&#x9;this is a div
        &#x9;&#x3C;/div&#x3E;
    </pre>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/TextMate");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Had this issue while embedding in a react component. Importing the given CSS through an `index.css` in `index.js` helped it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve by the following way. Run the code snippet for example.

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
        editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow_night");
        editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/xml");
        editor.session.setUseSoftTabs(true);
```

```css
#parent {
    width:50%;
    height: 600px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}
#editor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js"></script>
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="parent">
          <div id="editor"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [jquery-ace](https://cheef.github.io/jquery-ace/) I've managed this simply by using:

```
    $('#php_code').ace({
        theme: 'chrome',
        lang: 'php',
        width: '100%',
        height: '300px'
    })
```

Comment: You can do that without jquery in the same manner, just setting `width` to `'100%'`

Answer (score 3):

Reset its settings back to the browser default, which by design fit the parent container.

```
#editor {
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

I'm using the react-ace wrapper for reactjs.
It could be beneficial to any ace wrapper which have some defaults overwritten.

Comment: This seems to work for me, in my case the issue was with height, the editor was set to be full display height, it was right, but the ace_content class was always smaller, so with 3 lines I wrote it already started to scroll. How can this be working and not setting the height and width to 100% like the parent div?