# Ace editor - how to get the width of the editor so the parent div can be adjusted accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css, ace-editor

So I'm using Ace Editor to build a page with several coding editors. Each editor is inside its own column. However, if the code inside the editor has a width larger than it's parent div/container, then it will be necessary to scroll horizontally inside.

I'd like to find the width (if possible in `vw` units) of each editor in order to adjust automatically the width of each column, thus making the whole code snippet visible without having to scroll horizontally.

I solved this vertically using:

```
editor.setOptions({
  maxLines: editor.session.getLength()
})
```

but I cannot find an equivalent function in Ace's API.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785588/how-to-get-the-ace-editor-to-adjust-to-its-parent-div

Comment: @AndrewLyndem I had seen that before. Isn't that post about doing the inverse? Adjusting the editor to its div

Comment: Oh yeah, it is a solution for doing the opposite. My bad.

Comment: the code computing horizontal size is at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/virtual_renderer.js#L952