# ace editor is bigger than its parent div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ace-editor

I'm trying to use ace editor in my web pages.

ace editor github : https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace

on html body, I inserted ace editor div class in div "third-page" like this

```
<div id="third-page" style="display: none;">
    <div id="editor"> test </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="priv_3">Previous</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="next_3">Next</button>
</div>
```

and I declared stylesheet by following instructions in github tutorial.

but it was too small and I wanted to match its parent's size.

I found related stackoverflow page

[How to get the ace editor to adjust to its parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785588/how-to-get-the-ace-editor-to-adjust-to-its-parent-div)

and tried like this

```
#editor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

and the result was like this

[image]

[image]

div id "editor" is bigger than its parent "third-page" and I tried several things but it doesn't work.

how can I break through this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Set position of `third-page` to relative, to make absolute positioned children in it relative to that element instead of document.body