# How to access HTML divs in Javascript for Fifteen Puzzle game?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on this assignment, and have so far been unsuccessful in getting my code to work. I have to access these divs from an already existing HTML file:

```
<div id="puzzlearea">
            <!-- the following are the actual fifteen puzzle pieces -->
            <div>1</div>  <div>2</div>  <div>3</div>  <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>  <div>6</div>  <div>7</div>  <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>  <div>10</div> <div>11</div> <div>12</div>
            <div>13</div> <div>14</div> <div>15</div>
        </div>
```

And this is my current code iteration so far that I have also been unable to get working:

```
"use strict";

var ROWS = 4;
var emptyRow = 3;
var emptyCol = 3;
var SQSIZE = 100;

function pageLoad() {
    createPuzzle();
    document.getElementById("shufflebutton").onclick = shufflePuzzle;
}

window.onLoad = pageLoad;

function createPuzzle() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
        var square = $$("puzzlearea div")[i];
        var row = Math.floor(i / ROWS);
        var col = Math.floor(i - row / ROWS);
        square.id = "square_" + row + "_" + col;
        square.className = "puzzlepiece";
        square.style.top = (col * SQSIZE) + "px";
        square.style.left = (row * SQSIZE) + "px";
        square.style.backgroundPosition = (-col * SQSIZE) + "px" + (-row * SQSIZE) + "px";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated in getting the puzzle pieces to display correctly. The assignment directions also recommended me to NOT use a 2D array, so I have steered clear from that in order to meet the requirements. The variable declarations at the top are directly based on the assignment instructions.

I also can make NO changes to the existing HTML document.

Comment: Why don't you use css? Also, what is with the `$$`?

Comment: I have a CSS file, but I didn't include it because that's not where I was having the problems with. Also, I thought $$ was used for getting, like the document.getElementById()?

Comment: No, `$` is just an ordinary variable name in javascript (just like `ROWS` in your code). If you use jquery library, then `$` is assigned to jQuery function. If you are not planning on using jQuery, then you can use a `document.getElementById` to select the `puzzlearea` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the question is how to arrange a bunch of `div` elements in n(=4) columns.

```js
"use strict";

var COLS = 4;
var emptyRow = 3;
var emptyCol = 3;
var SQSIZE = 100;

function pageLoad() {
  createPuzzle();
  //document.getElementById("shufflebutton").onclick = shufflePuzzle;
}

window.onload = pageLoad;

function createPuzzle() {
  var puzArea = document.getElementById("puzzlearea");
  puzArea.style.position = "relative";
  var numSquares = puzArea.children.length;


  for (var i = 0; i < numSquares; i++) {
    var child = puzArea.children[i];
    child.style.position = "absolute";
    child.style.left = (SQSIZE * (i % COLS)) + "px";
    child.style.top = SQSIZE * Math.floor((i / COLS)) + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="puzzlearea">
  <!-- the following are the actual fifteen puzzle pieces -->
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
</div>
```

Although I haven't tested it, this should work with any number of div elements.

**Notes:**

- It is `window.onload` not `window.onLoad`
- To easily position the divs, I have used the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283417/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning). The same thing can be achieved using only css. In fact all Javascript code does is setting css properties.
- To get all child elements of the containing div (in this case `puzzleArea`, I have used `children` array ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children))

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This worked! I still have a lot of work to do, but this helped me beyond all measure. Also, thanks for including the links to how you did it so I can research that further.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on what ..

"I have to access these divs from an already existing HTML" means.

What have you tried?

You could append a data-attribute and reference that.
You could target using a library like jQuery nth-of-type. eg.

```
var seconddiv = jQuery('#puzzlearea div:nth-child(2)');
```

or javascript

```
var myPuzzle = document.getElementById('puzzlearea');
var myPuzzleItems = myPuzzle.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (i = 0; i < myPuzzleItems.length; ++i) {
  // logic for doing something with the elements 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS only answer:

```
<div id="puzzlearea">
  <!-- the following are the actual fifteen puzzle pieces -->
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
</div>
```

CSS using flexbox.

```
#puzzlearea {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flext-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#puzzlearea > div {
  min-width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but if you would like a nudge in the right direction...

You should look into childNodes, which you can read about here over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes).

Another good idea might be to read about [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or even  [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).

Best of luck on your assignment!

Comment: I didn't expect anyone to, I just need help on knowing where to go, thanks!